# Needs Google doc preview to upload the file for preview?

Tags: html, google-chrome, preview

I'm triying to preview doc, docx, pdf,... without install or use any extension/program so I will use the Google preview but i can't find further information of how to.

The problem is that I always have the same "No preview available" error. 
Can Google preview show a file that is in localhost? If I try to show a doc that is in my Google Drive the code is working.

This is for Liferay 6 and I'm trying to visualize in Google.

```
<%String enlace =  "https://docs.google.com/gview?url="+urlThatWorks+"&embedded=true"; %>


<iframe src='<%= enlace %>' width='1366px' height='623px' frameborder='0'>This is an embedded.</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Google doc preview would not be able to show preview of documents in your localhost. You need to make the document available over internet.